# "Subclass" MVC Extension

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, devexpress

I'm coming from a ASP.NET Webforms application. I'm using a third party control from which I created a descendant to set some default values. I then registered that class as a tag and I'm ready to go without setting the options ever and ever again.

Now I want to go to a MVC based application. I'm curious how to do that. Is there a way to "subclass" an extension there, too?

**Edit:** Done this with DevExpress MVC Grid extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third party control is another story entirely, and the vendor would have to release an ASP.NET MVC version.

However, in simple terms of creating re-usable code in ASP.NET MVC one option you have is to [create custom HTML helpers](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs).  It basically ends up being a method that you call which outputs markup, which can be made fairly powerful fairly quickly.

There are a *lot* of resources on various HTML Helpers, and keep in mind that the "documentation" you find on Google has changed significantly over the versions of ASP.NET MVC, so take care to ensure you're not limiting yourself to "an old way" of doing things.  There are also a number of commercial as well as free products and open-source projects with handy helpers and extensions.

Comment: The vendor has released an MVC version, I'm only searching for a way to incorporate settings centrally and not to repeat them over and over again. This is just required for some settings, while others are required to change.

Comment: @Sascha: I guess it depends on how the vendor's version is structured.  If it's a helper, then creating a custom helper which calls their helper should work (after all, it's just a method calling another method).  If it's a user control or some class-based structure, creating a wrapper class should do the trick.  In the end it should all come down to classes and methods, which can wrap and/or inherit as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I think I found a way thanks to your comment and will accept this answer.

Comment: @Sascha: Glad to hear it :)  My answer had to be a bit vague simply because I don't know the code/controls you're using.  But I encourage you to post an answer to this question in the future if you have more information on the subject from your own findings.  I imagine this is the kind of thing that other developers would love to see in a more concrete example.

Answer (score 1):

The third party control uses a Settings class. I have created a new settings class, which sets the default values in it's constructor.

Then I have written an extension method that reads like this:

```
public static GridViewExtension GridView ( this HtmlHelper html, Action<CustomGridViewSettings> settings ) {
  var mySettings = new CustomGridViewSettings();
  settings( mySettings );
  return html.DevExpress().GridView( (GridViewSettings)mySettings );
}
```

Usage is then analog to the samples online @DevExpress page and I omitted the sample class here.